# Construct promise flow from json

Tags: javascript, json, promise

My program has the following flow:

```
Promise.resolve(phase_1)
  .then(phase_2)
  .then(phase_3)
  .then(phase_4)
  .catch(errorHandler);
```

But i want but the phases in a flow.json:

```
[
  "phase_1",
  "phase_2",
  "phase_3",
  "phase_4",
]
```

But achieve the same result. Is it possible?

How i'm trying to:

```
let returning;
flow.forEach(function(phase, index) => {
   if (!index && !returning) {
     returning = Promise.resolve(require(phase));
   } else {
     returning.then(require(phase));
   }
});
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: If these phases are not co-related you may do `phasePromises = Promise.all(phases.map(phase => Promise.resolve(phase)); phasePromises.then(onFulfillment, onFailure)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are currently doing is equivalent to

```
let returning = Promise.resolve(phase);
returning.then(flow[0]);
returning.then(flow[1]);
returning.then(flow[2]);
returning.then(flow[3]);
```

To get the actual chaining, you'd need to do `returning = returning.then(…)` in your code. You can (and should) however simplify it a lot by using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) instead of `forEach` (which also fixes the problem of not doing the initialisation outside of the loop):

```
promise = flow.reduce(function(chain, phase) {
    return chain.then(phase);
}, Promise.resolve(phase));
```

Notice that `phase` is expected to be a function here, so if `flow` really consists of strings you probably had to do

```
    return chain.then(() => doSomething(phase));
```

Answer (score -1):

If these phases are co related then you may use Promises and Generators to utilize an asyc workflow such as; (poor man's coroutine)

```js
['1', '2', '3'].forEach(e => {function *iteration(index) {
                                // Some logic here
                                var val = yield Promise.resolve(index).then(v => { console.log(v); // do something with v
                                                                                   it.next(v);     // async by the job queue
                                                                                 });
                              }
                              var it = iteration(e);
                              it.next(); // start the engine
                             });
```